# R Studio error calling installed library on windows : there is no package called 'utf8'

Tags: r

I tried to install package `ggplot2`in R Studio Desktop Windows. But I got the error message when I used the library :

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Rifqi/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4068844 bytes (3.9 MB)
downloaded 3.9 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Rifqi\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp005k6i\downloaded_packages
> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘utf8’
>
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure but I would try to install `utf8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install package utf8 and then try reinstall ggplot2 and it should be fixed

```
install.packages("utf8")
```