# Why do I get "invalid input 'Guti"?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a forest plot on my meta-analysis. I typed

```
> meta1.for = update(meta1, byvar=EV, studlab=paste(Author, Year))
> forest(meta1.for)
```

Then I should get a plot according to my textbook but instead, I get

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : invalid input 'Guti>
```

It seems the first part is related to font issues but I don't have any information about the last part of 'invalid input 'Guti'. I don't know what's wrong with it.

I also typed

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(extrafont)
```

since somebody suggested it here but it said

```
Error in library(extrafont) : there is no package called ‘extrafont’
```

I also tried installing package "forestplot" and then tried again but it had the same error.

Comment: Not sure, but it feels like these are two likely-unrelated errors. For the "there is not package", have you tried `install.packages("extrafont")`? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66741120/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395807/3358272

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.