# How to resolve error "package ‘treeshap’ is not available for this version of R"?

Tags: r, shapley

if I try to run the treeshap function I get the following error

```
> TreeShapVal = treeshap(xgboost.unify(modelXG, x), x, interactions = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
Error in treeshap(xgboost.unify(modelXG, x), x, interactions = FALSE,  : 
  could not find function "treeshap"
```

If I try to install the treeshap package then I get the following errors

```
> library(treeshap)
Error in library(treeshap) : there is no package called ‘treeshap’
> install.packages("treeshap")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/BootMR/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘treeshap’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I am using RStudio 2023.06. I downloaded and installed RTools last week. I have no idea how to resolve and get the treeshap package to work?

Comment: which R version are you running? (this is a separate question to which Rstudio version)?

Comment: Actually having just looked, there is no package on CRAN called treeshap, either current or in the archive.  You will need to install from the github for the package.

Comment: Try:  `devtools::install_github('ModelOriented/treeshap')`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! it's R version 4.3.0

Comment: did installing from Github work?

Comment: For "could not find function", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/3358272. For "there is no package", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66741120/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395807/3358272. This is a duplicate of some or all of that.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen's comment to try "devtools::install_github('ModelOriented/treeshap')" resolved the issue :)

Comment: great to hear, will post as an aswer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no package on CRAN called `treeshap`, either current or in the archive. You will need to install from the github for the package. –

```
devtools::install_github('ModelOriented/treeshap')
```