# I have obtained some error trying to install maptools in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-maptools

Hello to everyone I would like to know how to install the package called "maptools" in R. I was trying to do it by hand, downloading from "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maptools/". But I can´t. After attempting the installation, the following error message appears.

```
"https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'maptools' ...
** package 'maptools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
Error in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  : 
  'make' not found
* removing 'C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/maptools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘E:/R_para_politicas_publicas/Clase_6/4_Econometria Espacial/Packages/maptools_1.1-8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status"
```

I would like to know either if someone can solve that installation problem or it's a problem with R, Rstudio or my windows 11 86*64.

Comment: This is a dupe of two sets of questions: "Rtools" https://stackoverflow.com/q/53279685/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239898/3358272; and "package unavailable" https://stackoverflow.com/q/66741120/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395807/3358272. You probably need Rtools43 installed anyway, though you can kick that can down the road by using [Posit's package manager](https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/) to install binary packages from specific dates (i.e. before `maptools` was retired). Ultimately, though, don't use `maptools` and install Rtools43.

Answer (score 3):

`{maptools}` is retired and binary is removed from *CRAN*, to build it from source you'd first need [Rtools(43)](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html). Though you could also install binaries from [Posit Public Package Manager](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/setup?snapshot=2023-10-13&distribution=windows&r_environment=ide) snapshots. As `{maptools}` was archived on 2023-10-16, snapshot from 2023-10-13 should do:

```
install.packages("maptools", repos = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-13")
```

If it's some legacy project you are working on, I'd consider setting up a `renv` environment with specific `repos` for this to keep those packages in project's package library and to avoid version conflicts:

```r
> renv::init(repos = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-13")
> install.packages("maptools")
# Downloading packages -------------------------------------------------------
- Downloading maptools from CRAN ...            OK [1.8 Mb in 2.4s]
Successfully downloaded 1 package in 7.8 seconds.

The following package(s) will be installed:
- maptools [1.1-8]
- sp       [2.1-0]
...
Do you want to proceed? [Y/n]: 
# Installing packages --------------------------------------------------------
- Installing sp ...                             OK [linked from cache]
- Installing maptools ...                       OK [installed binary and cached in 0.58s]
Successfully installed 2 packages in 0.67 seconds.
```

Comment: Your point about `maptools` being retired is true but I suggest ancillary to the underlying problem: the OP is unable to compile (`'make' not found`), therefore lacking Rtools; a fix of the _symptom_ (though having Rtools43 is still a good thing for many reasons) is to use Posit's package manager, which often has binary packages available. I suggest the suggested use of `renv` is tangential to the many problems.