# How can I convert the ArcGIS Shpae file to Arcinfo/Splus/Epimap format file to import adjajency matrix and Maps into WinBUGS

Tags: r, arcgis, winbugs

I want to convert the ArcGIS shapefile to Splus/ArcInfo/Epimap format so that I can input the adjacency matrix and maps into WinBUGS. WinBUGS can not read the ArcGIS shapefile directly. How can I do this using R or any software?

Comment: It looks like you'll want `maptools`, now retired, that has function `sp2WB`, [installing retired maptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511849/i-have-obtained-some-error-trying-to-install-maptools-in-rstudio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this at last

```
           install.packages("maptools", repos ="https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-13")

           library(maptools)

           library(sp)

           usa_counties <- readShapePoly("E:\\USA_Counties.shp", IDvar = 
            "CNTY_FIPS")

           # Convert to WinBUGS S-Plus format
          splus_data <- sp2WB(as(usa_counties, "SpatialPolygons"), filename 
           = "E:\\USA_Counties.txt")
```