# Maptools dependencies

Tags: r

Good morning,

I need to install the package maptools, but it has been removed from Cran. It is only available from Cran's archive. But before I install maptools from the archive I need to know what dependencies it uses. Anyone knows that?
Many thanks.

Comment: This should be asked in Stack Overflow, rather than here (this site is for statistical questions). However, I suggest going to the archive, unzipping it, opening the DESCRIPTION file, and then reading from Imports / Depends / Suggestions. That will tell you the dependencies

Comment: CRAN archive and building from source is not the only option,  you could also use some other repository, Posit Public Package Manager for example. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77511849/646761

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your answer. I have read the suggested post. It says that maptools can be install it by using the following code:

`install.packages("maptools", repos = "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/2023-10-13")`

I have added the date (2023-10-13, which the one on cran's archive). If I use this code to install it, will it install the dependencies?
In case it doesn't, I have read the description folder as suggest it. It sa

`Depends: R (>= 2.10), sp (>= 1.0-11) Imports: foreign (>= 0.8), methods, grid, lattice, stats, utils, grDevices Suggests: rgeos (>= 0.1-8), spatstat.geom (>= 1.65-0), PBSmapping, maps, RColorBrewer, raster, polyclip, plotrix, spatstat.linnet (>= 1.65-3), spatstat.utils (>= 1.19.0), spatstat (>= 2.0-0)`

Do I need to install only the imports or also the suggest packages.
Looking forward to receiving your answer.

Comment: @margusl I have used posit public package manager and I have installed maptools. Many thanks!