# How can I deal with this error when loading a package

Tags: r

I was using ahpsurvey package and suddenly got this error message after loading the package several times. I'm using jupyter notebook.

```
library(ahpsurvey)
```

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ahpsurvey' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called 'pillar'
```

How can I solve this problem?

I did a research on the package 'pillar' but couldn't find any clue

Comment: The error indicates that the `pillar` package is required but not installed. Have you tried `install.packages("pillar")` ?

Comment: Yes I tried but received same error message.

Also got this message when installing 'pillar'

--->Warning message in install.packages("pillar"):
"installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("pillar"):
"installation of package 'pillar' had non-zero exit status"

Comment: That suggests `pillar` did not install successfully - were there additional error messages after the install? You should do package installation outside of the notebook, check for successfull installs then restart the notebook and try again.

Comment: For errors like "there is no package called", I tend to defer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66741120/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47395807/3358272; in Rscript, things might be a little different, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673000/3358272.